# Play Framework Java8 connecting to MongoDB in Windows

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework

My application.conf is like this

```
mongodb.servers="127.0.0.1:27017"
mongodb.database="playDB"
```

I used [this example](https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Java-MongoDb-Jackson-exemple).

Here I declare my collection as this:

```
static JacksonDBCollection<User,String> usersDetails = 
        MongoDB.getCollection("logindetails",User.class,String.class);
```

But when I include this line:

```
List<User> loginlist=usersDetails.find().toArray();
```

I get an error like

> Execution exception
>   [Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/playDB]

I tried it by stopping mongo server and by starting it both ways.

Comment: you add mongo jakcson mapper dependencies in `build.sbt` ?

Comment: Can you connect to the mongodb with another client (RoboMongo for example)? (just to make sure the server is running properly.

Comment: try with localhost in place of loopback IP ( 127.0.0.1)

Comment: @Rakesh Chouhan-I am using localhost only.

Comment: @yogesh- yeah jockson mapper dependencies are added.